# WinDivert: redirect to proxy listening on loopback interface only

Tags: wfp, transparentproxy

trying to implement transparent proxy same way as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995343/windivert-redirect-to-proxy), but I have a "proxy" listening only on loopback interface. Once I set DstAddr to loopback, 2nd packet of TCP handshake never received

```
...
iphdr->DstAddr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
tcphdr->DstPort = ProxyPort;
addr->Direction = WINDIVERT_DIRECTION_INBOUND;
...
```

but it works if DstAddr = address_of_network_interface_packet_captured_from.

Also tried to alter `addr`:

```
    addr->IfIdx = 1;
    addr->SubIfIdx = 0;
```

without any effect.

Is there a way to implement such a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As with the original linked post, there does not appear to be any code here handling the reverse path (i.e. connection->proxy is handled, but proxy->connection is not).  This would explain why the `SYNACK` is never received.

For diverting to a local proxy see the [streamdump](https://github.com/basil00/Divert/blob/master/examples/streamdump/streamdump.c) sample program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Comment: but the point is I need to restrict proxy to loopback interface only (127.0.0.1).  My filter is (tcp.DstPort == 80 or tcp.DstPort == 443 or tcp.SrcPort == <proxy_port>) so I think it should handle 'proxy->connection' path?

Comment: if I modify [streamdump](https://github.com/mbg033/Divert/blob/develop/examples/streamdump/streamdump.c) so it runs proxy on INADDR_LOOPBACK and do appropriate changes in main loop, it stops working. Maybe any trick to inject/redirect to  loopback interface?

Comment: For reference, this issue is discussed further here: https://github.com/basil00/Divert/issues/82